# Rails configure rubocop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubocop

I am using pre-commit and rubocop gem in a rails 4 application.
I would like to escape quote checks which result in errors like 
`Prefer single-quoted strings when you don't need string interpolation or special symbols.`

This is what i have already tried in .rubocop.yml but it doesn't have the effect that I want.

```
Style/StringLiterals:
 Enabled: false
Style/UnneededPercentQ:
 Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 4):

you could try:

```
Style/StringLiterals:
  EnforcedStyle: double_quotes
```

Comment: Already tried that, and had no effect. But thanks for the tip

Comment: your file name is `.rubocop.yml`?

Comment: like `project/.rubocop.yml`? because it looks like your config is ignored

Comment: it is like project/config/.rubocop.yml and it doesn't seem to be ignored because if I add an option like `Metrics/LineLength:
  Enabled:false` I get less errors when running `rubocop`